# Is the "Watchmen" TV series a continuation of the movie or the comics?

Tags: watchmen, watchmen-tv

In the *Watchmen* TV Series it shows a bunch of people weathering Rorschach-like masks called the Seventh Kavalry who were inspired by Rorschach's writings about Adrian Veidt's (Ozymandias) conspiracy.

From my understanding the film's main plot about Adrian's conspiracy was the same as the comics, tricking the world to become united against a common foe and Rorschach being killed, but

- in the film it was against Doctor Manhattan by causing a generator explosion with his signature to make it look as if he attacked
- in the comics Adrian created an alien monster and set it out to attack

Is the series following on from the film or the comics?

Comment: Regina King on the Graham Norton show the other night described it as an "extrapolation".

Comment: judging by Lost and Leftovers, prepare to be highly engaged and intrigued at the start, and bitterly disappointed when the series ends. just sayin'.

Comment: @WillNess ["In that, if renewal was a given, how many seasons is your Watchmen?" / "I’m not being flippant when I say that the answer is one."](https://deadline.com/2019/10/watchmen-premiere-comic-con-damon-lindelof-inteview-regina-king-the-hunt-controversy-1202752460/)

Comment: @WillNess If you were bitterly disappointed by the end of The Leftovers, you are in the [minority](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt2699128/episodes?season=3&ref_=tt_eps_sn_3).

Comment: @RyanM thanks for the link. But what do those ratings prove? [nothing at all](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0411008/episodes?season=6&ref_=tt_eps_sn_6). :)

Comment: Does it have to be either?  If they can leave things ambiguous enough that people can't tell (e.g. by showing the aftermath of Ozymandias' attack, without showing *which* attack it was) then it could be the film, it could be the comics, or it could be an as-yet-unmade prequel series.

Comment: @Chronocidal Anyone who has watched the first episode knows which attack it is.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Ah, okay - as it's on a channel/service that I don't have, I haven't seen it.   But - since that would rule out it following on from one of the options -  perhaps you should expand that into an answer?

Comment: @WillNess Not sure what your point is; 9.5 puts an episode around the top 250 of all episodes of any TV show and 8.2 is somewhere around 7000. Season 3 of Leftovers is 99% on RT and 91% from users. What's your evidence that someone is at all likely to be bitterly disappointed?

Comment: my point was 8.9 is not 5 or 3.

Comment: While I can appreciate that LOST's ending is not everyone's cup of tea (it's my favorite ending and my favorite TV series though. I personally think most people don't understand the ending), the Leftover's ending is much better received and not as heavy on the metaphysics, although both are spiritual.

Answer (score 27):

The series' creator has ["explained" this in a letter](https://www.tor.com/2018/05/22/watchmen-tv-adaptation-remix-contemporary-damon-lindelof/):

> We have no desire to “adapt” the twelve issues Mr. Moore and Mr. Gibbons created thirty years ago. Those issues are sacred ground and they will not be retread nor recreated nor reproduced nor rebooted.
>
> **They will, however, be remixed.** Because the bass lines in those familiar tracks are just too good and we’d be fools not to sample them. **Those original twelve issues are our Old Testament.** When the New Testament came along, it did not erase what came before it. Creation. The Garden of Eden. Abraham and Isaac. The Flood. It all happened. And so it will be with Watchmen. The Comedian died. Dan and Laurie fell in love. Ozymandias saved the world and Dr. Manhattan left it just after blowing Rorschach to pieces in the bitter cold of Antarctica.
>
> **To be clear. *Watchmen* is canon.**
>
> [...]
>
> **But we are not making a “sequel” either. This story will be set in the world its creators painstakingly built… but in the tradition of the work that inspired it, this new story must be original.** It has to vibrate with the seismic unpredictability of its own tectonic plates. It must ask new questions and explore the world through a fresh lens. Most importantly, it must be contemporary.

---

From the December 2019 issue (no. 320) of ***SFX*** magazine:

> In the years since ***Lost***, Lindelof admits he’d been approached twice about adapting the book, which he says was flattering, but he was too scared to even contemplate it. But after he put ***The Leftovers*** to bed, he says the third time really was the charm.
>
> [...]
>
> “I was like, maybe there’s a version of *Watchmen*, as long as I don’t adapt the original which had already been done in 2009 by Zack Snyder. **What if I keep the initial 12 issues canon so that I’m not doing any rebooting?** Is there space for kind of a new story? **The show could be basically the ultimate intersection between a new story and potentially the continuation of the old story.** Because if I wasn’t making *Watchmen*, I would want to know exactly what happened to some of those characters.”

Comment: "_Watchmen_ is canon." - Well, at least we have that, but it's not really clear if by that they mean _Watchmen_ the comic or _Watchmen_ the movie. In the first quoted paragraph they talk about "the twelve issues", so we can assume they are talking about the comic. -- Btw. that's a lot of words about what the series _isn't_ and a painstaking attempt to absolutely refuse to put a label to it as to what it actually _is_. So Watchmen is canon (so it "happened"), but the series is not a sequel, but it takes place after Watchmen. Soo... a "continuation"?

Comment: @Corak Sound more like a [fanfiction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fan_fiction) to me.  But pro.  Is there such a meaning as "profanfiction"?

Comment: @Corak basically what they're saying is that they're using it as canon in the themes and broad strokes, but not tying themselves down to the details.  In particular, they're not tying themselves down to the sorts of details that are particular to a certain place and time.

Comment: @Corak He is obviously talking about the comic.

Comment: Think of "Fantastic Creatures and Where to Find Them" being set in the "Harry Potter Universe".  They are two storylines separated by decades of history.  What happened in one *may* affect the other but are not closely tied together.

Comment: "*Watchmen* is canon." - just a general question...Who "decides" what's canon? I can't imagine Alan Moore is okay with the series, and I'd bet he himself wouldn't consider it canon. ...Just found this [quote](https://qz.com/quartzy/1732050/why-alan-moore-wants-nothing-to-do-with-hbos-watchmen/): `“There is no version of Watchmen I could make that would please [Alan Moore],” Damon Lindelof, the showrunner of the HBO series, told Quartz last month. “Not only that, but there’s no version of Watchmen I could make that he would ever watch.”`

Comment: @BruceWayne - The ones who "own" the property. When Disney aquired Star Wars, they immediately un-canoned everything except the movies and the clone wars cartoon (IIRC).

Comment: @BruceWayne It is canon in the context of this TV series. Thus the showrunner decides.

Comment: @Corak As m1gp0z explained by way of the *Fantastic Beasts* example, a sequel is not just a work that occurs chronologically after the original, but one that continues the _same storyline_, i.e., focuses on the same characters. E.g. *Batman Beyond* is a "spinoff" rather than a "sequel" to *Batman: TAS* because it's about new characters (even though Bruce does appear a few times).

Comment: @BCdotWEB Yes, I think that's the more useful way to look at it, because canon is _directional_. The TV series may consider Alan Moore's comics canon, without Alan Moore considering the TV series canon. In the Star Wars example, Disney can't change which authors consider _each other's works_ to be in a shared canon, but they can choose which authors' works _they_ consider in the same canon as Disney-owned movies and TV series.

Answer (score 6):

It is following the 1986 Watchmen comics, not the 2009 movie adaption.

As the word-of-god answer was already given, here is how you can figure this out on your own by just watching the series.

The most glaring difference between the comics and the movie adaption, as pointed out in the question, is the nature of the attack on New York city.

> In the comic book, Adrian makes it look like aliens attacked earth by materializing a *giant squid* in the middle of the city. In the movies, he blames the attack on Doctor Manhattan, basically just blowing up the city and leaving behind some particle traces that look suspiciously Doctor Manhattan-y.

This is relevant as in the very first episode of the HBO series we see

> a weather phenomenon in which *hundreds of tiny squids* rain down on the city of Tulsa, disintegrating just moments after they hit the ground. It is later explained that these kinds of weather phenomena occur on a global scale as an aftermath to the initial "alien attack".

It should be noted that, much in the same fashion as Alan Moore used to radically modernize and often completely change the tone of the comic book series he adapted in the 1980s, HBO's Watchmen takes great liberties with the source material and focuses  heavily on themes that are not part of either of the previous adaptions.

Comment: You can update the answer with episode 7 to make it complete